# Compiler not following symbolic links in Visual Studio C++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, winapi, compiler-errors, header-files

I am using Visual Studio 2008 C++ project (Visa 32 bit).

I have the following *#include* directive in my source code.

```
#include <example/header.h>
```

In my include path I specify the **parent directory of 'example'**, i.e.

```
C:/.../include
```

where the full path to the header looks like

```
C:/.../include/example/header.h
```

However, 'example' is a **symbolic link** (A '.lnk' created via file explorer 'new shortcut'). I get the following error

> c:...\foo.cpp(37) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'example/header.h': No such file or directory

If I **replace the symbolic link with the actual directory**, the project will compile correctly. For practical reasons I need it to be a symbolic link. Is there anyway to make the Visual Studio pre-processor follow the link?

Comment: To make your question description a bit more clear, you might want to change 'example.h' to 'header.h' or something, as you later reference 'example' so at first it's a little hard to follow.

Comment: @Cam: Done. I've tried to re-word the question to make it more legible.

Comment: Much better ;) ...If you browse to `example` from your desktop, does it work properly? Also, are you using an actual "symbolic link", or are you using a "junction"? (that last question may seem pointless/obvious, but I just want to be sure)

Comment: @Cam: Viewing the symbolic link through the file explorer works correctly. The link is a symbolic link (.lnk), I did not even know what a junction was until I looked it up just now :).

Comment: @Akusete: I just tested and it seems to work fine for me. How did you create the symbolic link?

Comment: @Cam: Initially it was through a cygwin script 'using ln', but when I encountered the problem the first thing I did was to re-create the link using the file explorer 'new shortcut' method. Thanks for the confirmation that the links should work. I'll double check everything then, it narrows down the search.

Comment: @Akusete: Check my answer below - what you're creating is actually *not* a symbolic link, but rather a shortcut. Symbolic links do not have the .ink extension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The link is a symbolic link (.lnk)

Are you sure you're not creating a shortcut? Shortcuts work on a higher level than symbolic links and mean nothing to applications.

Conversely, symbolic links (if properly created) should work fine with any application that reads/writes to files/folders.

For more details, you may wish to consider reading this [article about symbolic links](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/), which explains how you can create a symbolic link using `mklink`.

Here's a helpful snippet from a comment on that article by "Bernard Kerckenaere":

> - shortcut: on the operating system level (to applications who wish to
>     read/write the link, it’s just a
>     meaningless file)
> - soft link (or symbolic link): like a shortcut, but on the filesystem level
>     (applications reading/writing the
>     link, will actually read/write the
>     file linked to)
>     ...
>     this will work across partitions, or drives
> - hard link: only for files, what happens is that there are multiple
>     file entries that point to the same
>     physical data, when you delete one
>     entry, the other will still work, the
>     data won’t be gone until all entries
>     are deleted (if with a soft link you
>     delete the original directory, the
>     link won’t work anymore!)
>     -> you can obviously only create hard links to a file on the same partition

What you want to create is a **symbolic link** which you can do with the `/D` parameter using mlink.

Comment: Ahh... I don't frequent windows much for development. I'm surprised 'ln -s', in cygwin created a '.lnk' file

Comment: I am porting a linux project to windows and the script generated header file links using 'ln -s', which on cygwin created shortcuts instead of actual symbolic links

Comment: @Akusete: Ah - that's annoying. I'm not incredibly familiar with *nix development or cygwin (although I'm working on fixing that!), but I don't think you can easily create a symbolic link through cygwin. Can you just replace the ln -s instances with calls to mklink?

Answer (score 1):

.lnk is not symbolic link, it is shortcut file for Explorer.
To create hard link, use

```
fsutil hardlink create link_name file_name
```

On Vista, there is **mklink** utility to create symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Visual Studio are a bit finicky when it comes to symlinks. Hard links on files using the `\H` parameter hardly ever work, but symlinking entire directories using `\D` is usually fine. Afterwards, you might need to remove and re-add the folder from and to your project, though.