# Linux Program can't find Shared Library at run-time

Tags: c++, linux, installation, g++, id3

I'm trying to compile a linux program, id3v2, and it says it is can't find the appropriate library:

```
id3v2: error while loading shared libraries: libid3-3.8.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing that this is the part that pulls in the lidid3 library?

The file DOES exist, however, what they are looking for is actually a symbolic link to:

> "ibid3-3.8.so.3.0.0"

I'm wondering if it is an issue with it not being able to follow symbolic links? Perhaps I could manually change it to look for 0.0 if I knew where I was looking to change it.

I'm happy to clarify any details.

It looks like the includes are done in the following manner:

```
id3v2:  convert.o list.o id3v2.o genre.o
        ${CXX} ${LDFLAGS} -pedantic -Wall -g -o $@ $^ -lz -lid3
```

I was able to use Simon's advice to figure out that there were multiple spots where one might expect a library.  I create a symbolic link where the program was linking to the ACTUAL file.

Thank you Simon!

Comment: Your title asks about the header, but your question's clearly about the shared library at runtime :-/.  You might check if it works if you add the directory containing the symbolic link to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

Comment: I clearly don't understand what I'm doing.  I will try to read your statement and see if I can follow your advice.

Comment: This might be promising... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490667/compiler-not-following-symbolic-links-in-visual-studio-c

Comment: Did you try running `ldconfig` as root?  This program makes a registry of available libraries used for runtime library loading.  The trick is that the library has to be in a place that `ldconfig` expects to see it, which depends on the distribution.  The list of library directories is usually in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or somewhere similar.

Comment: I just ran ldconfig as root.  No change.  But now  I know it exists!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Symlinks on libraries work fine, as long as the final target they trace to exists and is accessible.

You have built a dynamically-linked executable, that wishes to be linked against libid3-3.8.so.3 at execution time.  This was likely linked during the build phase with something like `-L/path/to/libid3/directory -lid3`.

You have a few *options* to make `libid3` available, in generally decreasing order of preference (since you didn't mention where the file was, I can only be general):

- Create a symlink to `libid3*` in a directory listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or `/lib` or `/usr/lib`)
- Copy `libid3*` to a directory listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or `/lib` or `/usr/lib`) (defaults)
- Add the directory containing `libid3*` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`
- Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/directory/path/to/libid3*` before running your id3v2 executable.
- Recompile `id3v2` statically. (It will work, but don't bother.)

After any of the first 3, rerun `ldconfig` so the linker cache is updated.  (You can then run `ldconfig -v` to verify it's resolvable.)

Note those aren't steps, they're options.  You only need to do 1 of them.

Glad you updated the title.  `#include` directives have nothing to do with linking.

Comment: Sorry about the directives, I have always "included" files in PHP, coldfusion and back with classic ASP.  So, I figured "include" would mean that it was including something...

Comment: It is including something: the header, which contains the declarations of functions and variable types, etc., so that the compiler knows variable types, method signatures, etc.  This is different from linking to a library, which provides access to concrete executable code either built into, or dynamically linked to the final executable.  It can be confusing when going from an interpreted language, since there is less distinction (from the programmer's perspective, anyway) between source and executable code.

Comment: Yeah, I have literally NEVER done anything with a compiled language.  I'm sure I will reread everything you have written multiple times.  Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how I would figure out where it EXPECTS the file to be?

Comment: It can be in any of the directories listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, or the defaults of `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.  The executable generally only has a library filename reference with no path.  The runtime linker (usually `/lib/ld.so` or `/lib/ld-linux.so` with some version number in it) checks all of its configured directories for the library, and then links them in every time the program starts.  If you just tell me the path where your `libid3-3.8.so.3` file is, I can give you exact commands.

Comment: Hint: It might still be in the source directory for id3v2.

Comment: ok.  I can for sure tell you where the file I'm looking for is... "/usr/local/lib/libid-3.8.so.3.0.0" and "/usr/local/lib/libid-3.8.so.3" Linx says "libid3-3.8.so.3: symbolic link to `libid3-3.8.so.3.0.0'"

Comment: Ok.  Just add `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (unless it's already in there; only put it once), then run `ldconfig`.  This will be easiest.  At that point, your `id3v2` program should be runnable.

Comment: Going to try one more thing that makes sense to me and if/after that fails I will go after what you just suggested. It never crossed my mind that there might be more than one folder...

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error you did, and after reading the solutions mentioned here, I resolved the problem (on Ubuntu 8) with:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libid3-3.8.so.3 /usr/lib/libid3-3.8.so.3
```

Answer (score 2):

This solved the issue just add `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (unless it's already in there; only put it once), then run `ldconfig`.