# Can't link BOTAN library with eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, g++, shared-libraries

I have installed and built the [BOTAN](http://botan.randombit.net/index.html) cryptographic library.

Everything seems correctly installed, since I have the following entries in `/usr/local/lib` directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7676350 2012-06-03 11:01 libbotan-1.10.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 2012-06-03 11:01 libbotan-1.10.so -> libbotan-1.10.so.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 2012-06-03 11:01 libbotan-1.10.so.0 -> libbotan-1.10.so.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   3396354 2012-06-03 11:01 libbotan-1.10.so.0.1
```

and in the `/usr/local/include` one too:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 2012-06-03 11:01 botan-1.10
```

And eventually I managed to include the libraries in the main of my program, and write code without error.

However when building my project (on Eclipse Indigo) I get the following output on console, with the red `stderr` fashion:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libbotan-1.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The code I'm trying to execute is the following:

```
try
{
    cout << "In try" << endl;
    Botan::LibraryInitializer init;
}catch(std::exception& e)
{
    cout << "In catch" << endl;
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
}
```

I have the following doubts:

1. Is it a problem of the Linker? (And if yes, why isn't the linker throwing the error, but the stderr?)
2. If not, how can I figure out to let my program find the `libbotan-1.10.so.0` file which is actually there? (in `/usr/local/lib`).

Note that my environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is currently set, and has the following value:

```
$> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$> /usr/local/lib/
```

---

**Compiler Command Line:**

Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler

```
g++ -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10 -O3 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -v -MMD -MP -MF"mainOobClient.d" -MT"mainOobClient.d" -o "mainOobClient.o" "../mainOobClient.cpp"

g++ -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10 -O3 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -v -MMD -MP -MF"oobClientClass.d" -MT"oobClientClass.d" -o "oobClientClass.o" "../oobClientClass.cpp"
```

Invoking: GCC C++ Linker

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o  "MTVS_oobClient"  ./mainOobClient.o ./oobClientClass.o   -lbotan-1.10
```

---

**Complete Build Output:**

```
Build of configuration Debug for project MTVS_oobClient

make all 
Building file: ../mainOobClient.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10 -O3 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -v -MMD -MP -MF"mainOobClient.d" -MT"mainOobClient.d" -o "mainOobClient.o" "../mainOobClient.cpp"
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.5 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multiarch-defaults=i386-linux-gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.5 --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 
Finished building: ../mainOobClient.cpp

Building file: ../oobClientClass.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10 -O3 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -v -MMD -MP -MF"oobClientClass.d" -MT"oobClientClass.d" -o "oobClientClass.o" "../oobClientClass.cpp"
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2' '-I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10' '-O3' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c++0x' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MFmainOobClient.d' '-MTmainOobClient.d' '-o' 'mainOobClient.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/cc1plus -quiet -v -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10 -MMD mainOobClient.d -MFmainOobClient.d -MP -MTmainOobClient.d -MQ mainOobClient.o -dD -D_GNU_SOURCE ../mainOobClient.cpp -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -quiet -dumpbase mainOobClient.cpp -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase-strip mainOobClient.o -g3 -O3 -Wall -std=c++0x -version -fmessage-length=0 -fstack-protector -o /tmp/ccLIYQkV.s
Finished building: ../oobClientClass.cpp
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) version 4.5.2 (i686-linux-gnu)

Building target: MTVS_oobClient
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  ./mainOobClient.o ./oobClientClass.o   -lbotan-1.10 -L/usr/local/lib -o  "MTVS_oobClient"
    compiled by GNU C version 4.5.2, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.0.0-p8, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/i386-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../../i686-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/c++/4.5.2"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
Finished building target: MTVS_oobClient
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include/botan-1.10

 /usr/include/c++/4.5
 /usr/include/c++/4.5/i686-linux-gnu
 /usr/include/c++/4.5/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include-fixed
 /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) version 4.5.2 (i686-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.5.2, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.0.0-p8, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 0c5cb630517b5952f4898dfa56d7e8e5
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2' '-I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10' '-O3' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c++0x' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MFmainOobClient.d' '-MTmainOobClient.d' '-o' 'mainOobClient.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 as -V -Qy --32 -o mainOobClient.o /tmp/ccLIYQkV.s
GNU assembler version 2.21.0 (i686-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.21.0.20110327
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2' '-I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10' '-O3' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c++0x' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MFmainOobClient.d' '-MTmainOobClient.d' '-o' 'mainOobClient.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.5 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multiarch-defaults=i386-linux-gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.5 --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2' '-I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10' '-O3' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c++0x' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MFoobClientClass.d' '-MToobClientClass.d' '-o' 'oobClientClass.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/cc1plus -quiet -v -I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2 -I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10 -MMD oobClientClass.d -MFoobClientClass.d -MP -MToobClientClass.d -MQ oobClientClass.o -dD -D_GNU_SOURCE ../oobClientClass.cpp -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -quiet -dumpbase oobClientClass.cpp -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase-strip oobClientClass.o -g3 -O3 -Wall -std=c++0x -version -fmessage-length=0 -fstack-protector -o /tmp/ccTuqeWw.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) version 4.5.2 (i686-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.5.2, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.0.0-p8, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/i386-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../../i686-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/c++/4.5.2"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include/botan-1.10
 /usr/include/c++/4.5
 /usr/include/c++/4.5/i686-linux-gnu
 /usr/include/c++/4.5/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include
 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/include-fixed
 /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) version 4.5.2 (i686-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.5.2, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.0.0-p8, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 0c5cb630517b5952f4898dfa56d7e8e5
../oobClientClass.cpp: In member function ‘void oobClientClass::authenticateTransaction()’:
../oobClientClass.cpp:126:29: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int scanf(const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
../oobClientClass.cpp:164:63: warning: ignoring return value of ‘ssize_t write(int, const void*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
../oobClientClass.cpp:59:6: warning: ‘confirmationChoice’ may be used uninitialized in this function
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2' '-I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10' '-O3' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c++0x' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MFoobClientClass.d' '-MToobClientClass.d' '-o' 'oobClientClass.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 as -V -Qy --32 -o oobClientClass.o /tmp/ccTuqeWw.s
GNU assembler version 2.21.0 (i686-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.21.0.20110327
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I/usr/include/c++/4.5.2' '-I/usr/local/include/botan-1.10' '-O3' '-g3' '-Wall' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-std=c++0x' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MFoobClientClass.d' '-MToobClientClass.d' '-o' 'oobClientClass.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: what is the actual compiler command that eclipse is executing?

Comment: @juanchopanza - added part...thks for letting me notice ;)

Comment: can you try typing that into the console, but with `-lbotan`, i.e. without the version number?

Comment: @juanchopanza - It was what I thought first, but in that case the linker gives an error: `g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o  "MTVS_oobClient"  ./mainOobClient.o ./oobClientClass.o   -lbotan
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbotan
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MTVS_oobClient] Error 1`.

Comment: Ah of course, the version is part of the name. Sorry about that, it was a nonsense suggestion.

Comment: @juanchopanza - never mind ;). Any other ideas?It seems as if the `LibraryInitializer` class can't find what it's looking for, and throws the exception...But it's really weird!!

Comment: actually, is the error when you link the executable, or when you try to run it?

Comment: @juanchopanza - i've added the complete build output. to me it seems that the build is successfully completed, and the program occurs with the execution of the binary file.

Comment: Ah OK, then it looks like the runtime doesn't know where to look for the library. On the command line the fix would be to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to "/usr/local/lib", or append to it if it is already set to something.

Comment: @juanchopanza - but that variable is already set...read the last line of the question above the compile commands...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming at run-time. You need to specify the rpath for the binary at build time - Where you have the:

```
-L/usr/local/lib
```

You also need:

```
-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib
```

This instructs `ld` to use this path when trying to find the library at run-time. Your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is probably being overridden by the launcher of eclipse, which is why the variable is not being used.

Alternatives:

Make sure that `/usr/local/lib` is in the `/etc/ld.so.conf`, and that `ldconfig` has been run after installing the library.

Link to the .a, using the command line:

```
g++ -o  "MTVS_oobClient"  ./mainOobClient.o ./oobClientClass.o -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lbotan-1.10 -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

or using:

```
g++ -o  "MTVS_oobClient"  ./mainOobClient.o ./oobClientClass.o /usr/local/lib/libbotan-1.10.a
```

... both should have the same effect

Answer (score 1):

Since the program build ends correctly, it is clear that it's a run-time problem due to the fact that the program can't find the Shared Library.

I looked for other people with same run-time issue and found out the solution (that I'll briefly sum up) thanks to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754633/linux-program-cant-find-shared-library-at-run-time).

What I did was to build the dynamically-linked executable, that wishes to be linked against `libbotan-1.10.so.0` at execution time. The linking during the build phase was done with command line option `-L/usr/local/lib`.

There are a few options to make `botan` (or any other library) available at run-time:

- Create a symlink to `botan` in a directory listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or `/lib` or `/usr/lib`)
- Copy `botan` to a directory listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or `/lib` or `/usr/lib`) (defaults)
- Add the directory containing `botan` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`
- Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` before running your executable.
- Recompile the program statically. (It will work, but don't bother.)

After any of the first 3, **rerun `ldconfig`** so the linker cache is updated.  (You can then run `ldconfig -v` to verify it's resolvable.)

Note those aren't steps, they're options.  You only need to do 1 of them.

Updating the linker cache with `ldconfig` made it work for me.